# Rest assured - Expected content-type "JSON" doesn't match actual content-type "text/html"

Tags: json, rest

I am getting below in response when i am expecting json response -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

whole page content

</html>
```

I am using rest assured to test the service -

```
Response response = given().accept(ContentType.JSON).when().get("link to my rest service");
```

even tried -> header("Content-Type", "application/json") and contentType(ContentType.JSON) but getting same result

Here is the rest service code -

```
@GET
@Path("/getUser")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setfName("Abc");
    user.setlName("Ben");
    user.setRacf("A1234");
    user.setEmpId("abcd12");
    return 
Response.ok(user).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
```

Comment: you are expecting a response in JSON format but server is sending response in text/html format. That is why you are getting this error

Comment: Yes, but why is server sending text/html and how can I fix this? if I hit the url directly from browser i get JSON response. I have my code above and @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) is expected to send json response

Answer (score 1):

The issue something your mistake, when are your sending get method http then the error be displayed. I change get -> post . This should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).